# Get width of element as painted on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a responsive design and trying to find the width of an element when the page is at 1500px wide. The div has padding in it so the width outputted when I right-click and inspect element is incorrect.

I tried opening the console and doing this:

```
var aDiv = document.getElementById('header');
console.log(aDiv.style.width);
```

and this:

```
var aDiv = document.getElementById('header');
getComputedStyle(aDiv);
```

but neither worked. How do I get the width, including padding, of a div as it is painted on the screen? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is possible.

Using jQuery -

```
$("elementnamehere").width();
```

If you want to change the element's width -

```
$("elementnamehere").width(80);
```

Change "80" to whatever width you want.

Remember the width calculated by the function is in px.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**clientWidth** is the inner width of an element in pixels. It includes padding but not the vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered), border or margin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth